# PG::Error: ERROR: null value in column "uid" violates not-null constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I setup a staging, and develop branch and now I'm getting this error when registering a new user locally:

```
    PG::Error: ERROR: null value in column "uid" violates
 not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains
 (7, test@gmail.com, $2a$10$WfiHKzYq4ovZtZoVAB.fRertuOSWezZYBw.RxkSqfBK89WbzcYxDK, 
null, null, null, 0, null, null, null, null, 
2013-08-13 07:20:13.484617, 2013-08-13 07:20:13.484617, 
null, null, null, null). : INSERT INTO "users" 
("created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "updated_at") 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "uid"
```

**schema.rb snippit**

```
create_table "users", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "id",                                  null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: ""
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: ""
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid",                                 null: false
    t.string   "username"
  end

  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
```

I can't push any new code to production until this is worked out, which is annoying :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `uid` is not-nullable but you aren't giving any values to it. Have your application generate one while you are registering users.

Ruby has a module named [Secure Random](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.9/classes/ActiveSupport/SecureRandom.html) which can be used to generate uids. It's usage is also pretty easy. Like,

```
require 'securerandom'
uid = SecureRandom.hex(10)
```

However, you can use [factory girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) to initialize your objects. For testing purpose though.

Comment: Would I put that in the create action?

Comment: Yes, where you are calling something like '@user.save'. just before that, call, '@user.uid = SecureRandom.hex(whatever-value)'.

Comment: Ah I see, that issue is I'm using devise so there isn't a users_controller to work with here. shit.

Comment: well, devise controllers are configurable too. check its doc https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code to create a new user in the database is not defining a `uid` value for the row. Your database has constrained that field to disable rows from ever having `uid` as null. Therefore, you should either remove this constraint from the database or change your code to pass through a `uid`.